# Weird Rails database errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've had some trouble getting my Rails app to connect to PostgreSQL so I decided to just say screw it and use SQLite for now. (I'm using the tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

I started a BRAND NEW, fresh Rails app from this tutorial. When I visit my app in the browser after deleting public/index.html, I get this the first time:

```
Please install the pg adapter: `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/pg_adapter)
```

That's odd to me because I'm not mentioning PostgreSQL anywhere. Here's my `databases.yml`:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

To make things more confusing, I only get that "pg adapter" error on the first load. For every subsequent page request, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

So even though I removed all mention of PostgreSQL, I'm still getting errors. What could be going on?

Comment: Have you restarted your server after the changes?

Comment: Could you show us the stacktrace associated with that error? it could contain useful information that will allow us to track down that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it works now for some reason. The only reason I can think of is that I shut down my server last night and restarted it today.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention doing `rails server` once you created the new web app, did you do this step, or are you still running the old server instance? you will know because the server will fail to start because there is already something running on port 3000. if you didn't shut it down, you need to run the following:

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

find the id of the process and

```
kill <id>
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Every time I want to restart it, I kill the old one and start a new one.